# String to NSDate problems

Tags: ios, nsdate

I can't get NSDate working for the life of me, even thought I've scanned the questions on Stack Overflow, so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSString *publishedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.published];
cell.publishedLabel.text = publishedText;
    return cell;
}
```

gives me the string:

```
2013-05-08 18:09:37 +0000
```

which I'm trying to turn into:
May 8, 2013 6:45PM

I've tried using:

```
    NSString *publishedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.published];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [df dateFromString:publishedText];
    cell.publishedLabel.text = dateFromString;
```

But it doesn't work and shows a warning that pointer types are incompatible (`NSString` to `NSDate_strong`).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is stupid: `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`.  Why initialize a variable and then overwrite that value on the very next statement??

Comment: Yeah I don't think that it was right.  @rmaddy got me the answer that worked perfect for me below

Comment: @Hot Licks cool comment bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have posted, it would appear that `feedLocal.published` is an `NSDate`.

Since your goal is to convert this date to a string, you need something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy h:mma"]; // this matches your desired format
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:feedLocal.published];
cell.publishedLabel.text = dateString;
```

Since your app can be used by people all over the world, I suggest you setup your date formatter like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Do this instead of setting a specific date format. Then the date and time will appear appropriate to all users of your app and not just those in a specific country.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a`NSDate` to a `NSString` `cell.publishedLabel.text = dateFromString;` (I suppose that the `cell.publishedLabel.text` is a `NSString`.

**EDIT**

I didn't test this code but I think the output should be ok if not please check iOS [date formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

So after you are parsing the string and you create the `NSDate` instance add the following code:

**EDIT 2 -- FULL CODE**

```
NSString *publishedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.published];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [df dateFromString:publishedText];

NSDateFormatter *secondDateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[secondDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
cell.publishedLabel.text = [secondDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes, `cell.publishedLabel.text` is a `NSString`, but I want the format to be different, and am not sure how to get that working?

Comment: Are you combining that with some of my code, or are those 3 lines all that you are using?  Because those three lines don't work for me, but I can't figure out what else you would be implying to combine it with?

Comment: Yes, those lines should be used with your code, after you are getting the NSDate from the string, but make sure that the `dateFromString` is not nil. Basically what you want to do is, convert from NSString to NSDate with one date formatter and from the obtained NSDate to a new NSStrng with another date formatter

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm getting `dateFromString` as `nil` though?

Comment: I edited my answer but just to be sure check the `df` date format to match your publishedText format.

Comment: @danypata Most of this code isn't needed since `feedLocal.published` is already an `NSDate`.